# Existing IOS certificate has no private key

Tags: trigger.io

I am trying to setup the IOS config on my windows machine. I already have a IOS developer certificate used for other non trigger apps.

I downloaded it and installed it on my windows machine. But when i export it using the instructions on this page there is no private key attached to the certificate.

http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/tools/ios-windows.html

Am i missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a certificate that is not associated with a private key in your keychain it usually means that you've downloaded a certificate that wasn't created using a request from your machine.

On your Mac, you need to create a certificate request from your keychain - if you click to create the certificate in the iOS provisioning center, it guides you through this process. You may need to revoke your existing certificate (as long as it's not being used) in order to then create a new one in the proper way.

Here are some good instructions that can take you through the process:
http://altf.wordpress.com/2010/02/20/preparing-devices-for-iphone-development/